# Including travel grants on CV

Tags: funding, cv

In the UK, a number of scientific associations like the [Royal Society of Biology](https://www.rsb.org.uk/get-involved/grants/travel-grants) or the [Institute of Physics](https://www.iop.org/about/support-grants) offer competitive travel grants to PhD students and early-career researchers. They are typically small in value, around £500. Nevertheless, it is funding that I have independently obtained, and I would like to include such travel grants on my CV for postdoc applications.

What is a good way to include such funding on a CV? I'm not sure if putting them under "grants" is the best approach because that's usually for research funding. Also, should I list all such small awards separately or, if I have several of them, just state that I obtained a number of travel grants totalling £XXX from organisations YYY and ZZZ?

Comment: At this point in your career, I would include them, especially if you have nothing else. They show you've done some successful grants.

Comment: Is it a competitive process? Or pro forma?

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- They are competitive grants indeed, which is one of the reasons why I think it's worth to highlight the funding in *some* way at least.

Comment: I had a similar thing. If you can find the award rate, and it's low, you can add that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest placing travel funding under the "Awards" heading, because they are funding for your travel expenses and not your research.  Funding for research I would call "Grants."

However, there are many reasonable ways to do it.  People are not much interested in small amounts of travel funding.